# Is it safe to use the TAG `android:switcher: + R.id.ot_pag_main + :0` to find a fragment?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I haven't seen this on the Android docs. Is it safe to use this automatically generated tag to refer to the fragments inside a viewPager?

Comment: The tag is typically available when `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` is invoked on the fragments in your adapter. It should be quite easy to add a tagged dummy fragment in the fragment manager that you can obtain from `#onCreate(..)` and register / pass the tags (by calling `#getTag()`) assigned to your fragments to this.

Comment: @Jens, thanks, I've seen implementations like the one you mention on your comment. This is actually how I realiced the tag was android:switcher... I really need to communicate fragments because a change in one fragment has to be shown in the other one too. I will probably use LocalBroadcastManager.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would not recommend it, as that is private data internal to the `PagerAdapter` implementation.

You are better served copying the `FragmentPagerAdapter` and/or `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` source into your project (refactored into your own package). Then, not only will you be insulated from any changes in the naming scheme, but you can even expose the methods used to generate those names.

The downside, of course, is that improvements made to those `PagerAdapter` implementations will not be available to you in the future unless you repeat the process.

Comment: And I assume that there's no constant to refer to this tag. I don't really get it. What's the best practice to comunicate fragments inside a viewPager? Even if I was going to do it through the activity that hosts them, how can the activity get an instance of the fragments inside the viewPager through the FragmentManager?

Comment: @HéctorJúdezSapena: "What's the best practice to comunicate fragments inside a viewPager?" -- with the standard `PagerAdapter` implementations, the "best practice" is not to communicate with the fragments. The adapters treat them as though they completely own them. This is yet another reason to consider doing your own `PagerAdapter`, whether a fork from the standard ones or a brand-new one you create yourself. "how can the activity get an instance of the fragments inside the viewPager through the FragmentManager?" -- they can't, reliably, because the tag is not known, as we discussed above.

Comment: ok, thanks! and thanksx2 because I did get a lot of inspiration from your WakefulIntentService too.

Comment: Thanks for this tip - I can confirm that I'm getting null pointer exceptions on a deployed app on a few devices, so I'm switching to a MyFragmentPagerAdapter approach like you suggested.